# Plot by using lines()

Tags: r, time-series

here is first few lines of my data

```
> data
     Price       Time
1   116800 2008-03-01
2   117200 2008-04-01
3   125100 2008-05-01
4   125300 2008-06-01
5   128700 2008-07-01
6   132900 2008-08-01
7   133500 2008-09-01
8   133700 2008-10-01
9   122900 2008-11-01
```

I try to manipulate it as a time series and plot my quadratic model but failed, here is my code:

```
t<-time(data$Time)
tsquare<-t^2
fit1<-lm(Price~t+tsquare,data=data)
plot(x=data$Time,y=data$Price,type="l",main="New Orleans House Price Trend S 
ince 2008",xlab="Time",ylab = "Price")
lines(y=fit1$fitted.values,x=as.vector(t), type='l',col="red")
```

Here is the error:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : plot.new has not been called yet
```

[The code runs without error but there is no red line pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ck3D.png)

Comment: I cannot replicate the error. When I run the code above, it works just fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrRsf.png Are you sure you are not getting a different error before that?

Comment: hi MrFlick, thank you for your answer.I run the codes before and it is all fine. When I run this in rmd chunk, there is no error pops up but the red line cannot shows.

Comment: Check if `time` is doing what you are expecting? Also, the what are the range of  `t`and `data$Time`.